# Signing app with xcodebuild command line with PROVISIONING_PROFILE fails

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

I trying to sign my app command line using Xcode.

Running `xcodebuild` command-line on `MyApp.xcodeproj` **like so**:

```
xcodebuild -project "MyApp.xcodeproj" -target "MyApp" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration *Release* PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer: something.com (SOMEVALUE)"
```

**Gives following error:**

```
Check dependencies
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: something.com (SOMEVALUE)".
Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" is Xcode managed, but signing settings require a manually managed profile.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'

** BUILD FAILED **
```

**What is wrong ? What is missing in my `xcodebuild` command ?**

**How can I include the signing certificate that its asking about ?**

***What I tried from answer & comments below***
As I understand, a dedicated `distribution profile` should be used with Release build. That is present in the system. I just need to know how to use it with `xcodebuild` command for manual signing if I can.

Executing `security find-identity -p codesigning -v | grep "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY"` gives a list of 5 signing identities ones of them clearly states as `iPhone Distribution: My Company (SOME123ID)`.

***So, can I use the distribution profile with xcodebuild manual signing? If yes, How can I get the actual ID of a distribution profile to use with xcodebuild command?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` is deprecated since Xcode8. Try `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` instead. `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="Human Readable Prov Profile Name"`

It may also be necessary to turn off Xcode's Automatic Signing:

Xcode9: simply append `CODE_SIGN_STYLE="Manual"` to your xcodebuild command

Xcode8: `sed -i '' 's/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;/ProvisioningStyle = Manual;/' TestApp/TestApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj && xcodebuild ...`

You can check your Xcode Version on the command-line with `xcodebuild -version`

Comment: I tried `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"` with `xcodebuild` command. I also tried the ID of the provisioning profile. Both didnt work. the error says `No iOS profile matching 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *' found:  Xcode couldn't find a profile matching 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.`

Comment: how can get the name of my provisioning profile. I am sure it is installed in the machine I am trying to make this work. since on that machine I am able to build+sign the app using Xcode UI editor. Just doesn't work command line

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to build your project with **Release** configuration but **Development** Signing? Seems a little odd. You may want to switch to `-configuration Debug` or explicitely configure Distribution Cert and Profile.
2. Double Check that the configured Cert is really linked in the Prov Profile
3. You can look up the profile's name in the profile itself: open in any TextEditor and search for <key>Name</key>
4. You may have multiple Profiles with the same name installed at `$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`. Be sure that all profiles have a unique name

Comment: Please dont mind. I am a little new in understanding this. I am trying to sign my app for **Release** build. why do you call it a **Development** signing ? I am with `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER="iPhone Distribution: My Company (98U8AKJSDF)"`. Something like this. Its a long list of `mobileprovision`s in `$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`.  Is it possible to get the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` from a mobileprovision` if one of them is correct ?

Comment: On Xcode UI IDE, if I drag & drop the  `provisioning profile` in use then it makes a `.mobileprovision`. Is there some way to get the correct **name of provisioning profile** from the `.mobileprovision` ? And input that into this `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` with `xcodebuild` command ? Looks like I am able to open the `.mobileprovision` with TextEdit

Comment: No problem :) `iOS Team Provisioning Profile ...` always refers to a development profile, so this doesn't help in your case. You need a distribution profile to match your distribution cert and release config. Do a backup of `$HOME/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`, then clear the folder, then let the Xcode UI build your project with *Release* configuration. Xcode's automatic Code Signing should download the proper Profile for your. You can then use the profile's name as value for `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER`

Comment: **Important question pls:** Is there a way to pass the `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` with `xcodebuild` command? Now its a different error. It says `Select a development team in the build settings editor that matches the selected profile`

Comment: You can override any buildsetting when calling xcodebuild, so you can of course do DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="ABCDEFGH" (should be 10 characters, see `<key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>` in your prov profile)

Comment: **A new error this time:**  `Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.myapp.something.something" is Xcode managed, but signing settings require a manually managed profile`. Something to do with the provisioning profile ? **thanks for the help until yet. Really appreciate**

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said above, you can not use Team Provisioning Profiles for Manual Release Builds. You have to setup a dedicated Distribution Profile. Or let Xcode's Automatic Code Signing do this for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149148/discussion-between-hal9000-kernel-and-sven-driemecker).

Comment: The dedicated distribution profile that you mentioned should be used with manual signing looks to be present in the system. I just need to know how to use it with `xcodebuild` command. Executing `security find-identity -p codesigning -v | grep "$CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY"` gives a list of 5 signing identities ones of them state as `iPhone Distribution: My Company (SOME123ID)`. ***So, can I use the distribution profile with xcodebuild manual signing. If yes, How can I get the actual ID to use with xcodebuild command?**

Comment: Is it possible to supply multiple profiles this way (in case you need to build app extensions more than one profile is required)?