# Manual signing with `xcodebuild` complains about missing signing certificate

Tags: xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, ios-provisioning

Looking at discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500634/use-xcodebuild-xcode-8-and-automatic-signing-in-ci-travis-jenkins-environmen/39598052#39598052), I am trying to manually sign my `iOS` in command line for CI.

I did a `sed` to replace automatic signing with manual signing as was required looking at discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500634/use-xcodebuild-xcode-8-and-automatic-signing-in-ci-travis-jenkins-environmen/39598052#39598052).

```
sed -i '' 's/ProvisioningStyle = Automatic;/ProvisioningStyle = Manual;/' MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

The ran the following command to manually sign using `xcodebuild`

```
xcodebuild -project MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj -scheme "MyApp" -configuration Release DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="97ARBCD76FG" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

**I get the following error:**

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't
>   include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: My Company
>   (97ARBCD76FG)". Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"
>   is Xcode managed, but signing settings require a manually managed
>   profile. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in
>   SDK 'iOS 10.3'

What am I missing for the manual signing to work with `xcodebuild`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signing app with xcodebuild command line with PROVISIONING\_PROFILE fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051712/signing-app-with-xcodebuild-command-line-with-provisioning-profile-fails)